# can't access my Ubuntu server after I changed the SSH port

Tags: networking, server, ssh, login, console

I can no longer access my digitalocean server running Ubuntu:

I changed the SSH port from 22 to 36734 this way:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and I changed the port from 22 to 36734

Then I rebooted the server. Now I can't access my server.

I'm using Putty and WinSCP to log on to the server. I also tried to access the console from the Digital Ocean control panel, and that did not work either.

Comment: did you check, after the service reload, that the service is running?

Comment: yes the server is working ,

Comment: Windows firewall? What about a log like you would get from`ssh -v`?

Comment: yes the problem was from the firewall of my university i tried alot but i didnt get attention to this after long time

Answer (score 0):

**the problem was from the firewall of the network in my university 
it was working with 22 but they block any other port because that i couldn't also enroll to the (access console ) of digitalocean 
what i did is i change the internet connection and i logged to my cpanel of digitalocean and i changed the port to 22 again**